# Kendo UI disabled input

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, editor

Kendo UI has alot editors. Using AngularJS all options can set in this style

```
<kendo-/editor/ options="Options"></kendo-/editor/>
```

And

```
$scope.Options = { dataSource: { ... }, ... }
```

I search for property "disabled" but cannot find anywhere. Kendo UI using Angular for Editors has not property disabled?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I found online while working on something similar sometime back. Create a custom directive:

```
.directive("kNgDisabled", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(e, widget) {
            var value = scope.$eval(attr.kNgDisabled);

            $(widget.body).attr("contenteditable", !value);

            scope.$watch(attr.kNgDisabled, function(value) {
              $(widget.body).attr("contenteditable", !value);
            });
          })
        }
      }
    });
```

and use it in the HTML as such:

```
<textarea kendo-editor k-ng-disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Kendo UI Options does not have any property for disabling the element. You can alternatively use ng-disabled (angular directive).